# Is this GIF a still image or an animation? (in Ruby)

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

How can I use rmagick to determine how many frames a remote GIF has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Magick::ImageList#length`](https://rmagick.github.io/ilist.html#length):

> Returns the number of images in the imagelist.

For example, this remote GIF:

[image]

has 12 frames:

```
require 'rmagick'
Magick::ImageList.new('https://i.giphy.com/zlLydol7ndM7C.gif').length
#=> 12
```